# How can I center Wave Trend Oscillator over 0-line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am displaying Wave Trend and RSI together on my indicator and I would really like to position the Wave Trend Oscillator at line 50 instead of line 0, how can I do that?

[RSI and Wave Trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G2NV.png)

```
//
study(title="WaveTrend [LazyBear]", shorttitle="WT_LB")
n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")
 
ap = hlc3
esa = ema(ap, n1)
d = ema(abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ema(ci, n2)
 
wt1 = tci
wt2 = sma(wt1,4)

plot(50, color=gray)
plot(obLevel1, color=red)
plot(osLevel1, color=green)
plot(obLevel2, color=red, style=3)
plot(osLevel2, color=green, style=3)

plot(wt1, color=green)
plot(wt2, color=red, style=3)
plot(wt1-wt2, color=blue, style=area, transp=80)
```

I don't know much pinescript so I need help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "50 + " in the plot series
Something like that:

```
//
study(title="WaveTrend [LazyBear]", shorttitle="WT_LB")
n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")
 
ap = hlc3
esa = ema(ap, n1)
d = ema(abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ema(ci, n2)
 
wt1 = tci
wt2 = sma(wt1,4)

p_zero = plot(50, color=gray)
plot(50 + obLevel1, color=red)
plot(50 + osLevel1, color=green)
plot(50 + obLevel2, color=red, style=3)
plot(50 + osLevel2, color=green, style=3)

plot(50 + wt1, color=green)
plot(50 + wt2, color=red, style=3)
p_WaveTrend = plot(50 + wt1-wt2, color=blue)
fill (p_WaveTrend, p_zero, color = blue, transp = 50)
```

Comment: This only adds or changes lines, what I want is for the indicator to start at 50 and not at 0

Comment: adds 50 to the oscillator too, but removes the Area style
for a similar style to the original, you can make a fill

Comment: I edited my answer, so you can see the complete code